# Paper-based algorithm to find longest formula which is common to at least two formulas

Tags: algorithms, optimization

Given a list of logical formulas:

- f1: A&B
- f2: A&D&C
- f3: B&D&E
- f4: A&B&C
- f5:

  fn: ...

In this case I want A&B as the longest formula which is common to at least two formulas.
Is there a simple algorithm to find the longest formula that could be performed on paper?

Comment: As I already  got two downvotes: Does the question need more information or something else?

Comment: Maybe people are wondering what you mean by "greatest common formula". I guess you mean the longest formula that's common to at least two formulas?

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen Yes, you are right. I was not able to express this myself. I will edit the question.

Comment: Is A&C also a valid answer?

Comment: Will all of your formulas be conjunctions of variables, or could they be something more complicated?  What's the definition of "common to two formulas"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each pair of formulas $f_i,f_j$ from your list, find the longest formula common to both $f_i,f_j$.  If things are as in your example, this is as simple as a set intersection.  That gives you $n(n-1)/2$ candidates.  Take the candidate that is the longest.